# Binary Search Tree Insertion C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Maybe asked million times before but I simply cannot understand what's wrong with this. I didn't want to use any code on the internet so I've just tried to program what's on my mind. Either this or my print function is wrong. Is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
void addNode(int value)
    {
        Node* newNode=new Node;
        newNode->data=value;
        if(root==NULL)
            root=newNode;
        else {
            Node* temp=root,*parent;
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                parent=temp;
                if(temp->data == value)
                    return;
                else if(temp->data < value)
                    temp=temp->left;
                else 
                    temp=temp->right;
            }
            temp=newNode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never assign the `left` or `right` member of any node.

Comment: I'm using 'temp=temp->left' and 'temp=temp->right'. Doesn't that count?

Comment: @rolandbishop: No; that changes your local variable to refer to a different node, but you don't modify the tree once you've found the insertion point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
temp=newNode;
```

This assigns the pointer to a local variable, which is discarded when the function returns, losing the new node. Instead, you want to assign it to a pointer within the tree; perhaps something like:

```
if (temp->data < value) {        // If the new node should be to the left
    if (temp->left) {            //   If there is a left subtree
        temp = temp->left;       //      Move into the left subtree
    } else {                     //   Otherwise
        temp->left = newNode;    //      Insert the new node there
        return;                  //      Done.
    }
}
```

and likewise for `temp->right` if `value < temp->data`.

Also:

```
if (temp->data == value) 
    return;
```

You have a memory leak there; you should `delete newNode` before returning.

Comment: I think he is also missing the case where you insert into the middle of the tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I guess I am a bit confused so this might come stupid but I didn't fully comprehend the reason that you check temp->left as 'if(temp->left'. Doesn't the while loop already provides that in case of a NULL value? I mean why do you have to check it with an if statement?

Comment: @JohnKalberer: Balancing the tree is an optimisation; better to get the basics working first.

Comment: @rolandbishop: The main loop stops once you've found a null pointer; but you need to reassign that pointer to point to the new node in order to add it to the tree. With my change, you won't need the test on the outer loop; you'll return once you find the insertion point.

Comment: Will this method be included in the same while loop? like 'while(temp!=NULL)'

Comment: You could change that to an infinite loop (`while (true)` or `for (;;)`), since with my changes you'll always exit the loop with a `return` when you find the insertion point, and `temp` will never be null.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thank you so much Mike! I've just implemented and it works. However I still have a weird feeling that the insertion has a much easier solution. Still 'even thought it is completely reasonable' I couldn't get to if statements. Is there any source you could recommend me that would show the implementation of iterative insertion operation?